# Android : Focus on TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` in `ScrollView` I need that when set text on `TextView` , going `foucus` on the `TextView` .I need that doing this work in `OnClickListener` a `Button` .

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: `txtview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` and `txtview.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set focusable as true.

```
txtview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

and then in onClick of button, request focus as:

```
txtview.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textbox.requestFocus();
            }
});
```

i really hope i understood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `setText` and then `requestFocus` like:

```
final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText("Some text");
        textView.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

*Note:*

TextView will have to be focusable. (`setFocusable(true)`, `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`).

Or in the xml:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```